# JQuery Dynamic Button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a input box. I enter the search term and the values get returned. What I am trying to do is click the dynamic button with the value attached to it. However when I click on the button it reloads the page instead of showing an alert box. This only happens with the dynamic button not the searchButton

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.cta-button').click(function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("You clicked the button");
        });

        $('#searchButton').click(function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            var varSearch = $('#searchDB').val();
            if (!varSearch) {
                $('#result').html("Please enter a search term");
                return;
            }
            $.ajax({
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: 'ID=' + varSearch,
                url: "getTest.ashx",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var result = '';
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        result += '' +
                            '<div class="main-area bg-white">' +
                            '<div class="row">' +
                                '<div class="medium-6 columns">' +
                                    '<button type="submit" id="OfferID_' + index + '" class="cta-button cta-button-icon">Add to Cart</button>' +
                                    '<br />' +
                                '</div>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '</div>'
                    });
                    if (!result) {
                        result = 'No data were found for ' + varSearch;
                    };

                    $('#result').html(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });


<section>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="medium-4 columns medium-centered">
            <div class="search-rewards">
                <input type="search" id="searchDB" />
                <button type="submit" id="button" class="button"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="medium-6 columns medium-centered">
            <div id="result">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Change from `type="submit"` to `type="button"`

Comment: @Dave I tried that too. It does not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the `event` argument to your `click` functions.  Without it, `event.preventDefault()` does nothing.

```
$('.cta-button').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("You clicked the button");
});
```

### Update

To bind to dynamic buttons, you'd need to use a delegate as @MACMAN suggested:

```
$(document).on('click', '.cta-button', null, function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("You clicked the button"); 
});
```

Comment: It does not make a difference, the page still reloads and no alert box is shown

Comment: Can you edit your question with the HTML that you're binding to?

Comment: If you're trying to bind to the dynamic button, then as @MACMAN suggested, you'll also need to use a delegate.

Comment: This solution works, and I upvoted. However, rather than capturing the submit event and cancelling it, it's better to just use a more appropriate button type that doesn't require the event to be cancelled. Changing the `type="submit"` to `type="button"` will eliminate the need to intercept the submit event.

Answer (score 1):

Use delegate to assign the click property to the dynamic button.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes JQuery events not working for dynamically generated elements. You can use JQuery.on() for dynamically generated elements.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

try using this

```js
$('.cta-button').on("click", (function() {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert("You clicked the button");
    });
```